# Populate a form field based on lookup value by AJAX

Tags: ajax

I am having a bit of trouble with working out how to populate a field on my custom object based on the selection of a related object record via lookup.

I have 2 custom objects - Case_Item__c and Item__c. I have a lookup on Case_Item__c to Item_c and would like to return the base_cost__c field from Item__c when the lookup field is populated.

I am using an apex:actionsupport component and wanting to retrieve the cost via AJAX.

The relevant part of the visualforce page looks like this:

```
<apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:actionRegion >
        <apex:pageBlockSection id="Item" columns="1">
            <apex:inputField value="{!CaseItem.Item__c}" > // Lookup field

                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!getItemCost}" rerender="Item"/>
            </apex:inputField>

            <apex:inputField value="{!CaseItem.Item_Cost__c}" /> // Cost Input field

        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:actionRegion>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

My Controller method looks like this:

```
public PageReference getItemCost() {

    Item = [
        SELECT
        Id,
        Base_Cost__c
            FROM Item__c
            WHERE Id = :CaseItem.Item__c
    ];

    CaseItem.Item_Cost__c = Item.Base_Cost__c;

    return ;

}
```

I am aware that my controller isn't returning anything, but also unsure of where to go from here or even if I'm on the right track.

Any assistance or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example for you to go by using a standard account

**CLASS**

```
public class myExample{

    Account a;

    public myExample(ApexPages.standardController con){
        a = (Account)con.getRecord();
    }


    public void letsDoIt(){
        a.BillingStreet = '123 Main Street';
    }

}
```

**Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="myExample">

<apex:form>
<apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:actionRegion >
        <apex:pageBlockSection id="Item" columns="1">
            <apex:inputField value="{!Account.Name}" > 

                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!letsDoIt}" rerender="Item"/>
            </apex:inputField>

            <apex:inputField value="{!Account.BillingStreet}" />     
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:actionRegion>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

In this example:

1. Enter an account name in the first input element
2. press TAB or otherwise loose focus on the input element
3. Observe that the Address int element is updated

In your example, your query needs to be hardened like so:

```
Item__c[] Items = [
        SELECT
        Id,
        Base_Cost__c
            FROM Item__c
            WHERE Id = :CaseItem.Item__c
    ];

if(!Items.isEmpty())
    CaseItem.Item_Cost__c = Items[0].Base_Cost__c;
```

Additionally, you may need to handle the case where multiple records are returned, etc.

Comment: I am still having issues getting the value from the lookup selection into the controller for use in the query (eg. WHERE Id = :CaseItem.Item__c). If I hard code an item id into this query it all seems to work as expected. Is there something I am missing about passing the lookup value id back to the controller?

Comment: @MattG - Without seeing your controller and how you are instantiating the caseitem it is hard to tell. In my example if you replace `a.BillingStreet = '123 Main Street';` with `a.BillingStreet = a.Name;` you will see the address field is updated to the same value you entered in the first input.

Comment: I have setup the case item variable as follows
    public Case_Item__c CaseItem {get; set;}

and in the constructor I instantiate a new CaseItem
    erCaseItem = new Case_Item__c();

Comment: If item__c is a lookup then you will need to enter the ID of the Item__c. Otherwise it will throw an error that it is an invalid ID. You may not be seeing the error if you do not have a Page Messages component on the page....Like I said, start small. Maybe make the input tied to a string and use the string to search for the item based on the Name instead of an id.